# How to pass multiple values as single parameter in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, string, oracle, plsql

I am trying to update values in multiple schemas which have the same table name.

So i tried to create query to pass multiple values as single parameter but its not working. Kindly suggest me.

```
DECLARE
    v_sql varchar2(500);
    v_schema varchar(30);
    v_prj_id varchar2(4000);
    in_PRJ_ID varchar2(4000);
    v_prj_id := 'B00781728,B00781628,B00781611,A43670001';

    CURSOR c1 is
      SELECT v_prj_id from DUAL;

BEGIN

    OPEN c1;

    FOR i IN (SELECT trim(regexp_substr(v_prj_id, '[^,]+', 1, LEVEL)) l FROM dual CONNECT BY LEVEL <= regexp_count(v_prj_id, ',') + 1 ) LOOP

        FETCH c1 INTO in_PRJ_ID;

        EXIT WHEN c1%NOTFOUND;

        v_sql := 'UPDATE ' || in_PRJ_ID || '.SI_Recipient set email = email ||'';Seshadri.K@iconplc.com'''  ;

        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_sql;

    END LOOP;

    CLOSE c1;

END;
```

Comment: When you say *"its not working"* what does that mean? Does it not compile? Does it hurl a runtime exception? Does it run but do nothing? Please remember we can't see your screen, we don't have your environments, we can't run your code.   **We only know what you tell us**.

Comment: Please see help section [ask]. Following that as a template greatly enhances you chance of getting a satisfactory answer. At a minimum post your table DDL, and describe what you are attempting to accomplish in business  terms NOT in SQL terms. The way all answers use your values they represent table names; of course this steams from your initial post. To reiterate APC on _its not working_, well of course, if it were you wouldn't be asking help. But **_why_** is it not working. If I just said: "it's not right" gives you the same amount of information, but is pretty useless

Answer (score 1):

Use a collection or a `VARRAY` for the values so you don't have to split a delimited string and you can use a bind parameter for the value you wish to append to your email string:

```sql
DECLARE
  v_sql     varchar2(500);
  v_schema  varchar(30);
  v_prj_id  varchar2(4000);
  in_PRJ_ID SYS.ODCIVARCHAR2LIST := SYS.ODCIVARCHAR2LIST( 'B00781728','B00781628','B00781611','A43670001' );
BEGIN
  FOR i IN 1 .. in_PRJ_ID.COUNT LOOP
    v_sql := 'UPDATE ' || in_PRJ_ID(i) || '.SI_Recipient'
             || ' set email = email || '';'' || :addr';
    BEGIN
      EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_sql USING 'Seshadri.K@iconplc.com';
    EXCEPTION
      WHEN OTHERS THEN
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( SQLERRM );
    END;
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

outputs:

> ```
> UPDATE B00781728.SI_Recipient set email = email || ';' || :addr
> ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
> UPDATE B00781628.SI_Recipient set email = email || ';' || :addr
> ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
> UPDATE B00781611.SI_Recipient set email = email || ';' || :addr
> ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
> UPDATE A43670001.SI_Recipient set email = email || ';' || :addr
> ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=664af437b0eb425b996cb4fe41a49072)*

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
Declare
  v_sql varchar2(500);
  v_schema varchar(30);
  v_prj_id varchar2(4000):='B00781728,B00781628,B00781611,A43670001';
BEGIN
  Dbms_Output.Put_Line('v_prj_id='||v_prj_id);
  --
  FOR i IN (SELECT trim(regexp_substr(v_prj_id, '[^,]+', 1, LEVEL)) l
            FROM dual 
            CONNECT BY LEVEL <= regexp_count(v_prj_id, ',') + 1 
           ) LOOP
      --
      Dbms_Output.Put_Line('---------------------');
      --
      --
      v_sql := 'UPDATE ' || i.l|| '.SI_Recipient set email = email ||'';Seshadri.K@iconplc.com'''  ;
      --
      Dbms_Output.Put_Line('v_sql='||v_sql);
      --
      begin
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_sql;
      Exception
        when others then
             Dbms_Output.Put_Line('sqlerrm='||sqlerrm);
      End;
      --
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

Output is:

```
v_prj_id=B00781728,B00781628,B00781611,A43670001
---------------------
v_sql=UPDATE B00781728.SI_Recipient set email = email ||';Seshadri.K@iconplc.com'
sqlerrm=ORA-00942: la tabla o vista no existe
---------------------
v_sql=UPDATE B00781628.SI_Recipient set email = email ||';Seshadri.K@iconplc.com'
sqlerrm=ORA-00942: la tabla o vista no existe
---------------------
v_sql=UPDATE B00781611.SI_Recipient set email = email ||';Seshadri.K@iconplc.com'
sqlerrm=ORA-00942: la tabla o vista no existe
---------------------
v_sql=UPDATE A43670001.SI_Recipient set email = email ||';Seshadri.K@iconplc.com'
sqlerrm=ORA-00942: la tabla o vista no existe
Total execution time 344 ms
```

Because in my oracle instance I don't have the schemas B00781728, B00781628, B00781611, A43670001 I get error ORA-00942 Table or view not exists.

Comment: Hi @alvalongo  Many thanks for the query.. it worked. I have one more question. i need to add where condition in that update statement like below 
    v_prj_id= B00781728,B00781628,B00781611,A43670001 

    v_event = A,B,C,D; i.e for B00781728 = A, B00781628 = B, B00781611 = C and A43670001 = D 
    --------------------- 
    v_sql=UPDATE B00781728.SI_Recipient set email = email 
    ||';Seshadri.K@iconplc.com' Where EVENT = V_event
in adition to this, i need to print the output of these result.